# Why should i use events and listener in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, events, listener

I understand events and listener in laravel but I don't know what difference between events and normal functions which means if I want to send mail why I should use event while I can use normal function to do that 
in another word, when must I use events and when must I use functions

Comment: To make testing your application harder.

Comment: It's a good way to separate out the logic. Mail functions in one class, logic in another. You can also use Events and Listeners in multiple places without duplicating the whole function. The [Event introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/master/events#introduction) explains a bit more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use event listeners over function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503723/why-use-event-listeners-over-function-calls)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An Event is a way of organizing triggers for reusable logic stored elsewhere in your application.

For example, say you have an application which registers users. When a user is registered, you may wish to take certain actions such as:

1. Email them a welcome email
2. Update a counter in a statistics database
3. Sign them up for a mailing list

***Functional Approach***

You could do this in a controller using functions like so (see the Pros and Cons under the example)

`RegisterController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    ...

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        // Create user
        $user = User::create();

        // Send Welcome Email
        $this->sendWelcomeEmail($user);

        // Update statistics database
        $this->updateStatisticsDatabase($user);

        // Add them to the mailing list
        $this->addToMailingList($user);

    }

    protected function sendWelcomeEmail(User $user)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected function updateStatisticsDatabase(User $user)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected function addToMailingList(User $user)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**Pros**

- This is self contained
- It is simple to follow

**Cons**

- This is a lot of responsibility for a single controller
- If you register users *anywhere* else in your application, you will need to duplicate each of the actions wherever you register users.

***Event / Listener Approach***

Alternatively, we can split this functionality into `Event`s and `Listener`s

`RegisterController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Events\UserWasRegistered;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    ...

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        // Create user
        $user = User::create();

        // Emit Event
        event(new UserWasRegistered($user));

    }

    ...
}
```

`UserWasRegistered`

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserWasRegistered
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

`SendWelcomeEmail`

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UserWasRegistered;

class SendWelcomeEmail
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Events\UserWasRegistered$event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserWasRegistered $event)
    {
        // Send the welcome email ...
    }
}
```

**Pros**

- You now have a `UserWasRegistered` event which you can call from anywhere in your application.
- The event guarantees that the same actions will happen no matter what triggers it
- If you ever need to add new functionality, all you need to do is create a new listener and register it with the event. Job done!
- You logic is separated and now the `RegisterController` has much reduced responsibility

**Cons**

- If you are only ever using the `Event` once, you now have logic spread over several files

**TLDR**

On simple applications, functional programming in a single controller may be all you need. In larger more complex applications, `Event`s and `Listener`s tend to be a much better option

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me more